# MYSQL BOOLEAN TRUE OR FALSE

Tags: mysql, boolean

I am using MySQL command line to create db tables etc. Below is my small user table script which is working ok:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
userid MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
sex VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
mailing_list BOOlean(100),
firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
joining_date DATE NOT NULL,
country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
usertype VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
comments VARCHAR(200),     
PRIMARY KEY (userid))
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now I want to add a `mailing_list` entry whose values should be Boolean or true/false.

What would be a sample script to do that?

Comment: "What will be the exact sample script for it?" - vote to close as too localized.

Answer (score 1):

To insert an entry in the `user` table you can use:

```
INSERT INTO user
VALUES (
    <user_id>,
    '<user_name>',
    '<password>',
    '<email>',
    '<sex>',
    <mailing_list>,
    '<first_name>',
    '<surname>',
    '<joining_date>',
    '<country>',
    '<user_type>',
    '<comments>'
);
```

Just replace `< x >` with the data you want to store. The `mailing_list` field is weird though. Boolean is sinonym of `tinyint(1)` and therefore doesn't have a length.